# TR is not being defined within the wrapper

Tags: python

```
...
def capital_gains(tr,rg):    
    tr = capital_gains(tr,rg)
    if int(rg) >= 40000:
        tr = 0
    elif int(rg) >= 40000 and rg>= 45850:
        tr = .15
    else: 
        tr = .20 
    return tr 


rg = 39000
print (tr)
...
```

I  am trying to chunk out tax rate (tr) in relation to the growth of realized gains (or rg). As this is tiered im trying to represent those tiers through if and elif.

Comment: You are not calling the function so ```tr``` is not defined

Comment: Your're also making an infinite loop (a real stackoverflow ^^ ) calling capital_gains function from itself without any limits. I think your `tr = capital_gains(tr,rg)` should be outside of the function itself. Also, you never initialize `tr` value in the first place.